# JCR can't add some helm repository

Tags: jfrog-container-registry

some helm repository can't be added to JCR => 
Connection failed: Error 404: Not Found
[image]

example: stratos https://cloudfoundry.github.io/stratos/
But if I do a https://cloudfoundry.github.io/stratos/index.yaml the file exist

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is just a bug with the **Test** connection due to the fact that https://cloudfoundry.github.io/stratos/ does not define a default index file. Functionality is fine.

If you **Save & Finish**, the repository still functions as needed (don't forget to put it behind a virtual repository as instructed).

I will issue a bug to solve the failed **Test** connection.

EDIT: Filed bug [RTFACT-21534](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-21534)